# Android RecyclerView OnItemTouchListener not functioning

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` showing a list of data. What I want to do is when the user taps on that item, it asks them if they wish to unlink that user. I have done this at various points in the application already and have written this code based on fully functioning `RecyclerView` `OnItemTouchListener`'s, but for some reason this is flat out refusing to register any clicks. The data populates the `RecyclerView` fine, it will just not let me click. Have I missed something obvious?

```
public void configurePage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "test = " + listOfIDs.size());
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(AgentViewUsers.this);
    mAdapter = new AgentUserViewAdapter(listOfItems);
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(AgentViewUsers.this);
            build.setTitle("Unlink this user?");
            build.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to unlink this user?");
            build.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // database code that deletes that user from firebase.
                }
            });
            build.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(AgentViewUsers.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // for loop that populates listOfItems from an already populated listOfIDs;
}
```

Comment: why you not try to put onclick in viewholder adapter?

Comment: As far as I'm aware I can't in this case, because I need the OnClick to do various bits to interact with Firebase and it relies on quite a bit of content that only exists in this activity. This is how I've been doing this in several other places in the application, and works as intended everywhere else, except here.

Comment: Just random comment, you might wanna call show() on that AlertDialog. Also maybe you are using a custom layout for the list item and that layout doesn't have different drawables for different states (i.e. pressed, released)

Comment: Okay, well now I feel stupid... this is what happens when you've been coding all day. Can't believe I missed build.show()!

Comment: I thought Android Studio used to give a warning if show() is not called.

Comment: I haven't seen it do it for ProgressDialogs and AlertDialogs, but I have seen it warn for not showing Toast popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might wanna call show() on that AlertDialog. Also maybe you are using a custom layout for the list item and that layout doesn't have different drawables for different states (i.e. pressed, released)